# Client not receiving emailed form contents

Tags: php, email, web-hosting

I've got a simple form post that's being emailed to a client on submit.

They are not receiving the form in their email. Doesn't seem to be a spam issue, as anyone on their domain won't receive the contents, and they've checked their spam filters.

If I send the contents to my email addresses on various mail servers and domains, I always receive them.

I call the host's support (mediaTemple) and they thought immediately what the problem--that the mail services were turned on for the web site, but mail was being handled by another machine (Google). Turned of mail services in the mediaTemple Plesk control panel. Client still isn't receiving emails. Any suggestions?

I've ommitted a bunch of the fields, but just so you all can get an idea of the PHP:

```
$to = "me@null.net, client@theirwebsite.com";
$subject = "Web Site Feedback";

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$date_of_visit = $_POST['date_of_visit'];
$first_visit = $_POST['first_visit'];

$body = "From: $first_name $last_name\n Date of Visit: $date_of_visit\n First Visit: $first_visit\n";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Client Name <client@theirwebsite.com>'. "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . "<client@theirwebsite.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-path: client@theirwebsite.com";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)
```

Comment: HTML body with no plain text alternative? Well, that's going to bounce its way towards a high score on a lot of spam filters.

Comment: You mean because of the "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" line? It's all text. Should I change that line? Though to be honest, the addition of the headers were added just recently. It was not showing up even before content type was defined.

Comment: If you want to send HTML formatted email, then send a multipart MIME email with a plain text alternative … and if you do that, get a proper library to do it rather then trying to hand craft a MIME routine.

Comment: It's just the text of a form. Assume that's changed to Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the mail function fails...

```
if (!mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
   echo "Failed to send email...";
}
```

If it works sending to a different email address that's not theirs, then it's definetly a spam issue.

You can try setting up an SPF record on the mail server to verify it's not spam and also consider using DKIM ([PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) have good DKIM support).

Comment: it definitely works for any email that's not a web site hosted on that box. They've got like four web sites hosted on that mt box, and none of those emails ever receive the form contents. Any other emails I append get them.

Comment: As I said, then it's definetly a spam issue. You need to look into methods to make the email seem more genuine, i.e. using a SPF record to tell the receiving server the sending server is authorised to send mail from that IP.